# Populate names in cell based on tiered choices using excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have 2 tables

First table is a list of items and 3 other columns depicting choice tiers

```
Items                             Choice 1          Choice 2          Choice 3

item1
item2
item3
item4
```

Second table has a list of users and their item choices. Item choices are distinct.

```
User                             Choice 1          Choice 2          Choice 3

user1                            item3             item1             item2
user2                            item1             item2             item4
user3                            item4             item3             item2
```

I want to populate the the users in the first table based on their choices. In the case above the first table should be populated like below.

```
Items                             Choice 1          Choice 2          Choice 3

item1                              user2             user1
item2                                                user2            user1 & user3
item3                              user1             user3            
item4                              user3                              user2
```

I will need to have multiple users in a single cell if their choice is shared with another user

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Hi @MoxGoat,, please [edit] the post & share the formula you have tried so far, will help us to fix it!!

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010+, you can use Power Query to generate your desired table from your 2nd table.

[image]

- Select the User Column and `Unpivot other columns`

  - This results in three columns as seen below:

[image]

- Then select the Attribute column and Pivot on that, with the Advanced Option of `Don't aggregate`

[image]

- However, this will result in an error for any cell that has more than one item contents.

  - Note that `Choice 3` contains `Item2` for two different users
  - We solve this by adding a custom aggregation function, to concatenate the results (*this option is not available in the UI*)
  - In the Advanced Editor, or in the Formula Bar, we change:

```
Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "User")
```

by adding:  `each Text.Combine(List.Sort(_)," & ")` as the optional aggregationFunction.

With some other steps along the way, to set data types, remove extra columns, and rename the `Item` column, the final code used is:

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"User", type text}, {"Choice 1", type text}, {"Choice 2", type text}, {"Choice 3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"User"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", 
        List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), 
        "Attribute", 
        "User",
        each Text.Combine(List.Sort(_)," & ")),
    
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Value", "Item"}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Choice 1", type text}, {"Choice 2", type text}, {"Choice 3", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Resulting in:

[image]

***Note:** If you decide to just paste the M-Code into the Advanced Editor, you'll need to ensure the Table name in line 2 is the same as the Table name of your data table in the workbook*